# Dynamic minimum and maximum dates using M/Power Query

Tags: powerquery, m

I have a calendar table that is created, on-the-fly, using `M`.

It starts like this:

```
let
    StartDate = #date(2016, 1, 1),
    EndDate = #date(2018, 12, 31),
    //Used for 'Offset' Column calculations, you may Hard code CurrentDate for testing e.g. #date(2017,9,1)
    CurrentDate = DateTime.Date(DateTime.FixedLocalNow()),
    // Specify the last month in your Fiscal Year, e.g. if June is the last month of your Fiscal Year, specify 6
    FiscalYearEndMonth = 6,
    #"==SET PARAMETERS ABOVE==" = 1,
    #"==Build Date Column==" = #"==SET PARAMETERS ABOVE==",
    ListDates = List.Dates(StartDate, Number.From(EndDate - StartDate)+1, #duration(1,0,0,0)),
    ...
    ...
```

Is it possible to make the first two lines dynamic so that they pick up minimum and maximum dates from database tables? So these two lines:

```
let
    StartDate = #date(2016, 1, 1),
    EndDate = #date(2018, 12, 31),
```

I have another table being loaded into the model using the following - can I somehow use the Date column from this loads to dynamically set StartDate and EndDate ?

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("ourServer", "ourDB"),
    tb_ModelFact = Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="tb_ModelFact"]}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(tb_ModelFact,{{"Date", type datetime}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each true),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filtered Rows",{{"Amount", type number}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

---

Edit

So I tried this

```
StartDate = List.Min(Fact[Date]),
EndDate = List.Max(Fact[Date]),
```

....and got this mysterious error?

```
Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value #datetime(2016, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0) to type Date.
Details:
    Value=06/01/2016 00:00:00
    Type=Type
```

Is this error in subsequent M code after the declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You should be able to write something along these lines:

```
let
    StartDate = List.Min(tb_ModelFact[Date]),
    EndDate = List.Max(tb_ModelFact[Date]),
```

where `tb_ModelFact[Date]` is the column that has the dates you are trying to take the max and min from.

You will need to change `tb_ModelFact` to whatever the name of that second query is though.

Comment: So maybe the error is due to a subsequent section of the m code that builds the calendar table?

Comment: @whytheq I'm guessing you are mixing date and datetime value types. Maybe try making the `Fact` table date column a date type instead of a datetime on the `#Changed type` step.

Comment: (....not quite - but I'll play and try and track down my extra new errors)